# My Tiva C launchpad is resetting everytime the motor is plugged in

Tags: microcontroller, tiva-c

For this project I have 2 motors connected to my device. The one motor that is currently on there works perfectly on both terminals. I'm confident in my code being correct, and the soldering should be good as well since the one motor works on both terminals. I also checked the voltage coming out of the terminal that belongs to the second motor and it works perfect. Then, when I attach the motor that's when the software resets. I would comment that function out and it would work again. Attached is the schematic of my two motor connections. The terminal blocks up top are used later. I'm using the power from my PC for power which is connected to 3.3V. I already replaced the motor and checked to make sure that it works with 3.3V. It works so just wondering what is going on.

[image]

Comment: I assume Tiva launchpad is a kind of microcontroller. How is this connected? Does it share the supply with the motor circuit? Did you open your PC to extract 3.3 V from the internal ATX supply?

Comment: how do you know that `software resets`? ... maybe the hardware is resetting ... maybe because of low voltage ... what are you using for power? ... did you measure the power supply voltage when both motors are connected?

Comment: @Jens It is connected through a USB port of my computer. It does share power to the motors.

Comment: @jsotola It is connected on the USB port of my computer and that is true about low voltage. Let me check that.

Comment: Are you powering the motors with USB power? Bad idea.

Comment: @Mattman944 It's part of the project to use the USB. I've done it in the past using PWM, but for this specific lab I have to use the USB power.

Comment: I don't grasp what you're doing exactly. Are you connecting this trouble-making motor while your Tiva C is running and provides power to the connectors? What happens if you connect the motor while the Tiva C is off, and then power the whole circuit up? Are both motors of the same type or are they different? Did you check the motor by powering it directly from the supply?

Comment: @thebusybee The motor is connected before I connect it to the computer. I also tested both terminal blocks and found that they both are working supplying the right amount of voltage which is 3.3v. It is when both motors are connected that's when I run the software and the code will run the first motor and then get to the second motor and it just resets back to the beginning of main and keeps repeating this. The two motors are different. I tested this motor on a different power supply with 3.3v and it work just fine. It is only when I connect it to the TIVA C board.

Comment: Well, then the given answer points in the right direction. You need to decouple the power supplies, by the proposed way, or other means. For example, capacitors work wonders.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to guess how the development board is connected in your system. If you must use the power from USB, don't pass it through the development board. The +5V and +3.3V development board outputs are provided as a convenience; they should only be used for low-power peripherals.

Instead use a USB Y cable to get power to the Motor driver without going through the development board. If supplying power this way doesn't fix the issue, you may need filter the power to the motor.

[image]